# Script to select specific radio buttons in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, radio-button

So at my job I have a queue of things to annotate.  There's about 18 questions for each of these things I'm annotating and each one has a set of radio buttons with answers I need to select.  So for the most part my answers are usually the same.  So I want a script or code that I can enter in the Chrome console that will automatically select those radio buttons.

Now keep in mind I have no programming knowledge besides some HTML and that's it.  This is the code I've been using to select the last answer which I then have to go and change some of them manually:

```
javascript:document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]").forEach(e=>e.click());
```

What would be a code that would pick specific radio buttons.  So for example, viewing this page's source, this is the first set of question and answers:

```
<label id="RESP_3_1_Appearance_option-set-label" for="RESP_3_1_Appearance_option-set" title="How would you .........?" class="">How would you rate the appearance of the individual's arms?<span class="help-icon"></span><div class="">

<label id="RESP_3_1_Appearance_option-set-5-label" for="RESP_3_1_Appearance_option-set-5" title="How would you...?" class=""><input id="RESP_3_1_Appearance_option-set-5" name="RESP_3_1_Appearance_option-set" type="radio" option-value="5" value="">Answer 1 sdfsdfsdfsdf.</label>

<label id="RESP_3_1_Appearance_option-set-4-label" for="RESP_3_1_Appearance_option-set-4" title="How would you...?" class=""><input id="RESP_3_1_Appearance_option-set-4" name="RESP_3_1_Appearance_option-set" type="radio" option-value="4" value="">Answer 2...</label>

<label id="RESP_3_1_Appearance_option-set-3-label" for="RESP_3_1_Appearance_option-set-3" title="How would you...?" class=""><input id="RESP_3_1_Appearance_option-set-3" name="RESP_3_1_Appearance_option-set" type="radio" option-value="3" value="">Answer 3....</label>
```

And each question is similar to that structure.  So yeah what would a code be for doing something like that, and what would I end up changing in the given code for each additional question and answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code sets the value checked of a radio button to true.

```
document.getElementById("ID").checked = true;
```

Note: you must replace `ID` with the correct id of each element.